# Searching and sorting

Tags: java, sorting, search

Here is the problem I am trying to solve....

---

The Shell sort is a variation of the bubble sort. Instead of comparing adjacent
values, the Shell sort adapts a concept from the binary search to determine a
‘gap’ across which values are compared before any swap takes place. In the
first pass, the gap is half the size of the array. For each subsequent pass, the
gap size is cut in half. For the final pass(es), the gap size is 1, so it would be
the same as a bubble sort. The passes continue until no swaps occur

---

Here is my code:

```
public class Shellsort {

    protected int[] array= {9,6,8,12,3,1,7};
    protected int gap;


    public Shellsort() { 
        gap=array.length/2;
        for (int y=0; y<=gap; y++){
            for(int a=gap; a<=array.length; a++){
                if(array[y]>array[array.length]){
                    swap(array[y],array[array.length]);
                }
                a++;
                y++;
            }
        }

        public int swap (int x, int z){
            x=array[y];
            z=array[array.length];
            return (z, x);
        }

    }
}
```

---

This is what I was able to come with, can someone recommend me some advice/input for finishing this problem.

Comment: Your `swap` can't work.

Answer (score 0):

array[array.length] is invalid because the index starts at 0. To get the last element in an array you would do array[array.length - 1]